# Is it possible to cast in a MongoDB-Query?

Tags: mongodb, casting, mongodb-query

When I have two MongoDB documents like this...

```
db.test.insert( {"value" : "10123"} );
db.test.insert( {"value" : "160"} );
```

The result of a query like:

```
db.test.find({"value" :{$gt : "12"} });
```

is..

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4c6d1b92304326161b678b89"), "value" : "160" }
```

It's obvious, that a string comparison is made, so that my first value is not returned.
Is there any way to cast within the query?

Something like:

```
db.test.find({ (int) "value" :{$gt : 12} });
```

would be great. A query like

```
db.test.find({"value" :{$gt : 12} }); // without the quotes around "12"
```

returns nothing.

Comment: Is there a reason that you are storing integers as strings? Wouldn't be better to do db.test.insert({"value":10123});

Comment: That's true, of course.. In my application I collect formvalues and pass them on to Mongo. POST and GET values are string-typed by default. I suspected the driver would take care of the type conversion. Unfortunately that's not the case. So your're right, I convert the data before inserting. 
Also, @niels made a good point... using a javascript-expression actually solves the problem.

Comment: I face this problem in 2020 :). I think that it would be good type cast numeric string values to integer before storing it in db. So I am gonna do it before storing in db.

Comment: @OzalZarbaliyev : Yes you're write - you need to take care of these scenarios on writes, but MongoDB now provides a way to deal with these, Check this :: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62178861/7237613

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the following [JavaScript expression](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-JavascriptExpressionsand%7B%7B%24where%7D%7D):

```
db.test.find("this.value > 12")
```

This uses JavaScript's automatic conversion from string to number.

Comment: just be careful since that can't use indexes

Comment: does this still work? looks like is not working for array elements

Comment: db.test.find("this.value > 12") this is not work for me and I try with this db.test.find({$where: "this.value > 12"}) now its working

Answer (score 4):

I have a similar workaround, i find that if you can use the mongo shell, you can write an statement to do this in javascript, but capable of using indexes.

```
var myItems = []
var it = db.test.find({},{value:1})
while (it.hasNext()){
 var item = it.next();
 if(parseInt(item.value) > 12)
  myItems.push(item);
}
```

If you want this to run faster than previus solution, you have to ensure the index on the value field.

Comment: This doesn't really use indexes for what you really need the index for

Answer (score 3):

Type casting in MongoDB is available after version >= `4.0`. Check MongoDB's aggregation operator [$convert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/convert/index.html) and similar operators. Since you wanted to convert `string` to `int` you can use `$toInt`:

```
db.collection.find({ $expr: { $gt: [ { $toInt: "$value" }, 12 ] } })
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OgJwSKZc_GK)

**Note :**

Here we're converting `value` which is a `string` field to `int` on the fly & Since it got converted to `int` - we're comparing it to input of type `int`. Your output documents will still have original type for `value` field which is `string` (we're not actually changing type in response docs, if needed use aggregation & it's stage `$project` to see `int` values for field `value` in response docs).

Since we're using aggregation operators in `.find()` we need to wrap everything in `$expr`.

Even though this is pretty common nowadays & is easy to do, but remember we're casting `string` to `int` on every Read, rather if you can take care of this on Writes or Updates it would be easy & more efficient.

Comment: If you get any issues while conversion first check if input from field is valid or not on all docs & also refer to documentation. Just in case if your `value` field has a mix of **double** & **int** then you can just use `$toDouble` instead of `$toInt` - But remember if you're using conversion & returning converted value then `"10123"` will look like int `10123` but is type **double** `10123` - since you've used `$toDouble`. So if you've string (double & int) mixed on same field & wanted to maintain types as is then use `$cond` to check if string has `.` then use `$toDouble` else `$toInt`..

Answer (score 2):

To convert String into int use this

```
db.test.find({'year': {$type: 2}}).forEach(
    function (x) {
        x.value=new NumberInt(x.value); 
        db.test.save(x)}
    )
```

And after that you can directly query like :

```
db.test.find({"value" :{$gt : 12} });
```

Answer (score 0):

$gt wasn't set for this use case.  You would have to use regex for strings.  Probably easier to just create a new field with the number as a number.