# Converting a mysql query to mongodb using php

Tags: php, mongodb

Currently I have an mysql table like this:

```
+---------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| mediaID | int(11)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date    | datetime | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

In this table I store every hit made for a specific media. I save mediaID and date when this hit happened. So ... when I want to show trending medias (most viewed medias for specific time period), I use this mysql query:

```
SELECT  mediaID, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM hits WHERE DATE(date) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY GROUP BY mediaID ORDER BY cnt DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

Now.. I'm planning to move this in MongoDB. Currently I have collection "hits" with the following documents:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("50827eaaae1c3ced6c00000f"),
    mediaID: "2",
    ts: ISODate("2012-10-20T13:36:26+03:00")
}
{
    _id: ObjectId("50827ebeae1c3ced6c000010"),
    mediaID: "1",
    ts: ISODate("2012-10-20T13:36:46+03:00")
}
{
    _id: ObjectId("50827ec3ae1c3c6167000008"),
    mediaID: "2",
    ts: ISODate("2012-10-20T13:36:51+03:00")
}
```

So, my question is how to convert my previous query to be able to work with MongoDB? 
P.S. I'm using php with php mongodb driver.

Greetings,
Milen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/).  You want to only count hits from the last 24 hours, group them by mediaID and then order highest to lowest and show top ten, right?

In the shell:

```
today = new Date();
// this gets you yesterday but you can change this to be any time period
cutoff = new Date(today.getYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate()-1);
db.hits.aggregate( [
   {$match: {ts: {$gt: cutoff} } },
   {$group: {_id: "$mediaID", cnt: {$sum: 1} } },
   {$project: {mediaID: "$_id", cnt:1, _id:0 } },
   {$sort: { cnt:-1 } },
   {$limit: 10}
] )
```

You will get back for sample data you showed:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "mediaID" : "2",
            "cnt" : 2
        },
        {
            "mediaID" : "1",
            "cnt" : 1
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Asya Kamsky but how can I convert it to php?

Comment: Nevermind. I have able to convert it to php. Thanks a lot @asya-kamsky

Answer (score 0):

Just another advice.

Because you use `int` with `mediaID`, but the data with your `mediaID` in mongodb is using `string`, you should use `intval()` to convert the data before storing it into `mediaID`.

There are some issues(ex: comparison) if you use `string` instead of `int`.
[Is it possible to cast in a MongoDB-Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521601/is-it-possible-to-cast-in-a-mongodb-query)