# How to cast a MongoDB query and use Index

Tags: sql, mongodb, postgresql

I have a sql query that I want to convert to MongoDB and still use the index. Here is the sql query

```
SELECT * FROM "Data1" WHERE age > Cast('12' as int)
```

According to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3521714/184773) answer the above query can be converted to:

```
db.test.find("this.age > 12")
```

However, using this syntax will not use any indexes. I wanted to know has this issue has been fixed for MonoDB.

Comment: this should work: db.test.find({age: {$gt: '12'}})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [$gt](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/) operator, to make use of indexes.

```
db.test.find({age:{$gt:12}})
```

The field `age` should be indexed.

> *I wanted to know has this issue has been fixed for MongoDB.*

It still can't be achieved.

The doc says, If you need to use java script for evaluation and select documents, you need to use the [$where](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) operator. But it would not use the index.

```
db.test.find( { $where: "this.age>12" } );
```

From the docs,

> $where evaluates JavaScript and cannot take advantage of indexes;

Hence whenever query criteria is evaluated as Java script , it can never make use of indexes.

Comment: how to do for this : count =12; db.test.find({age:{$gt: count}})