# How to use MongoDB find() to perform range queries on numeric strings?

Tags: python, mongodb

How can I make a `find()` in MongoDB, using find to be >= with some value, but that value is a numeric string?

If I run the following line (that searches the MongoDB database for modes higher than 1):

```
cursor = db.foo.find({"mode": {"$gt": 1}})
```

This will work only if the data in MongoDB is in the format:

```
data = {"mode":3}
```

But I need to use the `find()` with this data:

```
data = {"mode":'3'} # as string
```

**How can I do this?**

**Here is my example:**

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient()
db = client.test

db.foo.drop()

data = {"mode":3} # Works because this is a numeric
data = {"mode":'3'} # Won't work!!!!!!!!!! But my database contains only numeric strings...how can use like this?

db.foo.insert_one(data)

print(db.foo.count())

cursor = db.foo.find({"mode": {"$gt": 1}})

for document in cursor:
    print(document)
```

Comment: what is the reasoning behind numeric Strings? can't you store then as numbers and convert to String at application level?

Comment: unfortunately the database is already like this... I can't change it.

Comment: Depending on how large your collection is, I'd suggest you to update your document and make it of proper type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you leave your numeric data stored in the database as strings, in order to query your data with range operators such as `$gt` and `$lt` you're going to have to use one of two approaches.

First, you can use JavaScript's automatic conversion to run your range queries. This works as shown below, but it is very limited as you will **not** be able to use any indexes, as explained in the comments to previous answers. Thus for big data sets, this will be prohibitively slow.

```js
db.foo.find("this.mode > 1");
```

A second approach would involve regular expressions. You will have to figure out what regex to use, but once you have that, you can use the syntax below to run your query or use the `$regex` operator as highlighted [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#op._S_regex).

```js
db.foo.find({ mode: /pattern/<options> });
```

Aside from having to figure out some complex regex, again there are possible performance issues with this approach, as explained [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#index-use) (see extract below). Most likely, you will also run into issues where your query is not taking advantage of indexes.

> If an index exists for the field, then MongoDB matches the regular expression against the values in the index, which can be faster than a collection scan. Further optimization can occur if the regular expression is a “prefix expression”, which means that all potential matches start with the same string. This allows MongoDB to construct a “range” from that prefix and only match against those values from the index that fall within that range.

Because of this, if you're going to be running these queries often, I would recommend that you follow a third approach, which would be to change your schema and store your data as numbers. You can achieve this with a simple migration script such as the following in JavaScript, which you could run in the shell.

```js
var cursor = db.foo.find();
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
  var doc = cursor.next();
  var _id = doc._id;
  if (doc.mode) {
    var modeString = doc.mode;
    var modeInt = parseInt(modeString);
    db.foo.update({ _id: _id }, { $set: { mode: modeInt } });
  }
}
```

Having done that you will be able to query your data using operators such as `$gt` and `$lt`, sort it without much hassle, and take advantage of indexes.

Comment: when use above code(case 3) it says:  hasNext  is not a function. (How to slove that one)

Comment: Are you running this in the shell? Make sure you're using the `find` method and not the `findOne` method.

Answer (score 1):

From [Mongo docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/),

*$type selects the documents where the value of the field is an instance of the specified BSON type. Querying by data type is useful when dealing with highly unstructured data where data types are not predictable.*
*{ field: { $type: BSON type number | String alias } }*

***$type returns documents where the BSON type of the field matches the BSON type passed to $type.***

I guess you'll have to pass the $type explicitly in your case which might be:

```
data = {{"mode":{$type:"string"}}:'3'}
```

Comment: Thank you. I've tried the: cursor = db.foo.find( {"mode": {"$type":"string" | {"$gt": 1}}} )
But it won't work either. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm not sure what this answer is supposed to do, $type will return all documents where the type is string, not the ones compared to anything. It's not a cast operator.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this synthax (JavaScript's automatic conversion):

```
db.test.find("this.mode > 1")
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3521714/5815127)