# Mongodb: convert array values from string to geo-coordinates

Tags: mongodb

In MongoDB database, I want to convert the values of the array "location" into geo coordinates(get rid of double quotes).

Now I have:

```
{"location" : ["12.962828", "37.987717"]}
```

I need:

```
{"location" : [12.962828, 37.987717]}
```

How can I do?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to cast in a MongoDB-Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521601/is-it-possible-to-cast-in-a-mongodb-query)

Comment: @Danielle: I need to stable convert array values.
I tried parseInt, parseFloat with the code below, but the result is:
{location: NaN,NaN}:

 `db.strutture.find({Codice: "xx-yy-zzz-111"}).forEach( function (x) {
 var long = parseFloat("x.location.0");
 var lat = parseFloat("x.location.1");
 x.location = [long,lat];
  db.strutture.save(x);
});`

Answer (score 0):

I got it, there was an error in the way I was pointing to the array value; I was using dot notation in the MongoDB style while I should have used [].

This is the working code to update all collection's documents:

```
db.strutture.find().forEach( function (x) {
    var long = Number(x.location[0]);
    var lat = Number(x.location[1]);
    x.location = [long,lat];
    db.strutture.save(x);
});
```